# How to read only the lines in a text file when text starts at nth position

Tags: python-2.7

I have a configuration text file I need to parse. Looks something like this:

```
    agateway:
       cl_profile: "sl6.5-x86_64"
       prefix: "aicgateway"
       primary_role: "STANDARDV3"
       requires_pool: false
    ac-edge:
       cl_profile: "sl6.5-x86_64"
       prefix: "ac-edge"
       primary_role: "STANDARDV3"
       requires_pool: false
    webnode:
       cl_profile: "centos-5.6-x86_64-db-v2"
       vlans: ["frontend"]
       label: "Frontend"
       prefix: "web"
       primary_role: "FRONTEND"
       requires_pool: false
```

I would like to build a list just from the server pool types, 
['agateway', 'ac-edge', 'webnode'].
Thinking just put into cache only the lines starting 4 spaces in, then parse out the colon.
Any ideas on best Pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: what format is the configuration file and are the attributes per server pool static / consistent?

Comment: PyNoob, it's a yaml file. But for parsing, I think could just approach as a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to parse the wanted data:

```
import re

with open('file', 'r') as file_:
    data = re.findall(r'\s+(.+):$', file_.read(), re.MULTILINE)
print data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about only reading in the lines that start four spaces in, but one approach could be to read the whole thing and then only select the lines that end in a colon, taking off the colon while you go. This might be more Python 3 syntax since that is what I am used to, but the list comprehension should be pretty much the same either way:

```
data = []
with open('my_file', 'r') as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        data.append(line.strip())  # all lines, minus white space
data = [d[:-1] for d in data if d[-1] == ':']
print(data)
# ['agateway', 'ac-edge', 'webnode']
```

So basically, read your file line-by-line into a list, then use the list comprehension to only grab what you care about. You could accomplish something similar by only appending lines that end with a colon to your list:

```
data = []
with open('my_file', 'r') as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        if line.strip()[-1] == ':':
            data.append(line.strip())
print(data)
# ['agateway', 'ac-edge', 'webnode']
```

Comment: Thanks Engineero, but cince every line ends in colon, gives me back much more than I need. Trying to take advantage of the fact the lines I need have less indentation.

Comment: @ArinEkandem This worked fine on the example you gave, wherein only the lines that you say you care about end in a colon. If that isn't the case, I suggest giving a more representative example.